# Disable cache for specific sites in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser-cache

Is there a way to tell Chrome to disable caching for specific sites? I'm doing dev work, and I'd like to avoid caching `localhost`.

Comment: I already found this question, which says that there isn't a way to do what I'm asking for. But it was asked over two years ago, and I'm wondering if things have changed since then. http://superuser.com/questions/217642/can-i-disable-the-cache-in-chrome-for-specific-hosts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're doing development work you probably have the DevTools open. If you press the settings button in the DevTools window (bottom right) and select the General tab. There you will find the option "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)". Check that option and the cache will be disabled whenever you have the DevTools open.

I'm using Chrome 28 on Linux and think it's available on all platforms as described [in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/settings).

Comment: I know about this solution. I'm mostly doing back-end work, though, so having dev tools open feels like wasted space to me. If there's a way to disable the cache per site without the dev tools, I would prefer that. (+1 to your answer because it's good anyway, though.)