# Clear all browsing history but keep visited links for certain sites

Tags: google-chrome

Occasionally I want to clear my browsing history, but for certain sites I don't want to lose visited links.

For example on websites on the Stack Exchange network I still want to know which posts I've already visited.

Is there a way to delete all browsing history except for the visited links of certain sites?

I could of course manually delete all history entries except for those of certain sites, but this requires a lot of manual work which I would like to avoid.

Comment: Possible duplicate [1](https://superuser.com/q/1572039/152004), Related: [2](https://superuser.com/q/217642/152004)

Comment: @Rubén I've updated the question. It's specifically about having the visited status of pages be remembered for certain sites. As far as I know and from testing, this is affected by the browsing history and not the cache or cookies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visited links are apparently stored inside a Visited Links binary file.

Located at `~/.config/chromium/Default/Visited\ Links` on my system.

I haven't been able to find a way to delete every visited link from this file except for certain URLs.

What does work is:

1. Saving a copy of the Visited Links file somewhere.
2. Deleting all browsing history.
3. Closing the browser.
4. Moving the Visited Links file back to the `~/.config/chromium/Default` directory.

When you open the browser again all visited links are kept, but other browsing data is cleared.

Answer (score 0):

I can only speak for FireFox. Click History in Menu bar and choose last seven day ..or more.. history shows on the right. Hold 'ctrl key' and click each link.Should highlight on click. Continue until your finished. Don't click anymore. Let go of 'ctrl key'. Right click 'not left click'. In the pop up window select delete and left click. Highlited links are gone and preferred links are left alone. I do not use Chrome. That you will have to explore. Avoid mistakes...do the research. Good luck, wilson.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but like I mentioned in my question I'm looking for a way where I can avoid having to manually delete every history item except for those of certain sites.